# Spark Dataframe write to kafka topic in avro format?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-kafka, avro

I have a Dataframe in Spark that looks like

> eventDF

```
   Sno|UserID|TypeExp
    1|JAS123|MOVIE
    2|ASP123|GAMES
    3|JAS123|CLOTHING
    4|DPS123|MOVIE
    5|DPS123|CLOTHING
    6|ASP123|MEDICAL
    7|JAS123|OTH
    8|POQ133|MEDICAL
    .......
    10000|DPS123|OTH
```

I need to write it to Kafka topic in Avro format 
currently i am able to write in Kafka as JSON using following code

```
val kafkaUserDF: DataFrame = eventDF.select(to_json(struct(eventDF.columns.map(column):_*)).alias("value"))
  kafkaUserDF.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)").write.format("kafka")
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "Host:port")
    .option("topic", "eventdf")
    .save()
```

Now I want to write this in Avro format to Kafka topic

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Spark >= 2.4**:

You can use [`to_avro`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-avro.html#to_avro-and-from_avro) function from [`spark-avro`](https://github.com/databricks/spark-avro) library.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.avro._

eventDF.select(
  to_avro(struct(eventDF.columns.map(column):_*)).alias("value")
)
```

**Spark < 2.4**

You have to do it the same way:

- Create a function which writes serialized Avro record to `ByteArrayOutputStream` and return the result. A naive implementation (this supports only flat objects) could be similar to (adopted from [Kafka Avro Scala Example](https://dzone.com/articles/kafka-avro-scala-example)  by [Sushil Kumar Singh](https://dzone.com/users/2946333/sushilkumarsingh.html))

  ```
  import org.apache.spark.sql.Row

  def encode(schema: org.apache.avro.Schema)(row: Row): Array[Byte] = {
    val gr: GenericRecord = new GenericData.Record(schema)
    row.schema.fieldNames.foreach(name => gr.put(name, row.getAs(name)))

    val writer = new SpecificDatumWriter[GenericRecord](schema)
    val out = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    val encoder: BinaryEncoder = EncoderFactory.get().binaryEncoder(out, null)
    writer.write(gr, encoder)
    encoder.flush()
    out.close()

    out.toByteArray()
  }
  ```
- Convert it to `udf`:

  ```
  import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf

  val schema: org.apache.avro.Schema
  val encodeUDF = udf(encode(schema) _)
  ```
- Use it as drop in replacement for `to_json`

  ```
  eventDF.select(
    encodeUDF(struct(eventDF.columns.map(column):_*)).alias("value")
  )
  ```

Comment: typo : `import org.apache.spark.sql.funcitons.udf` Please change `funcitons` to `functions`

Comment: Unfortunately Avro schemas are rarely flat in production, and this doesn't support the Confluent Avro format for Kafka. Besides that, you only need a GenericDatumWriter

Comment: How to revert it back or deserialize it back after consuming from kafka? @OneCricketeer

Comment: @supernatural I'd suggest creating a new post