# Trouble porting Scala spark code to PySpark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I found an example of encoding the rows of a Spark DataFrame to Avro in Scala.

credit:
[Spark Dataframe write to kafka topic in avro format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47951668/spark-dataframe-write-to-kafka-topic-in-avro-format/47952472#47952472)

My applications are written in Python and I'm having trouble porting the code from Spark to PySpark. Here is the Scala code:

**Scala:**

```
import org.apache.avro.Schema
import org.apache.avro.Schema.Parser

import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData
import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericRecord
import org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificDatumWriter


import org.apache.avro.io.EncoderFactory
import org.apache.avro.io.BinaryEncoder

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream

import org.apache.spark.sql.Row

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

def encode(schema: org.apache.avro.Schema)(row: Row): Array[Byte] = {
  val gr: GenericRecord = new GenericData.Record(schema)
  row.schema.fieldNames.foreach(name => gr.put(name, row.getAs(name)))

  val writer = new SpecificDatumWriter[GenericRecord](schema)
  val out = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
  val encoder: BinaryEncoder = EncoderFactory.get().binaryEncoder(out, null)
  writer.write(gr, encoder)
  encoder.flush()
  out.close()

  out.toByteArray()
}

val SCHEMA_STRING = """
{
    "namespace": "kakfa-avro.test",
     "type": "record",
     "name": "User",
     "fields":[
         {   "name": "name",  "type": "string"},
         {   "name": "num", "type": ["int", "null"]}
     ]
}
"""


val df = Seq(("Mary", 1), ("Brad", 2)).toDF("name", "num")

val schema = new Schema.Parser().parse(SCHEMA_STRING)
val encodeUDF = udf(encode(schema) _)

df.select(encodeUDF(struct(df.columns.map(column(_)):_*)).alias("value"))
```

**PySpark:**

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, struct, udf, lit
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType, ByteType

def encode(schema, row):
    """
    """
    import io
    import avro.schema
    import avro.io
    import json

    avro_schema = avro.schema.Parse(json.dumps(schema))
    writer = avro.io.DatumWriter(avro_schema)

    bytes_writer = io.BytesIO()
    encoder = avro.io.BinaryEncoder(bytes_writer)
    writer.write(row, encoder)

    return bytes_writer.getvalue()


encode_udf = udf(encode, ByteType())


SCHEMA = """
{
    "namespace": "kakfa-avro.test",
     "type": "record",
     "name": "User",
     "fields":[
         {   "name": "name",  "type": "string"},
         {   "name": "num", "type": ["int", "null"]}
     ]
}
"""

df = spark.createDataFrame([('Mary', 1), ('Brad', 2)], ('name', 'num'))

df.select(encode_udf(lit(SCHEMA), struct([col(c).alias(c) for c in df.columns])).alias('value')).show()
```

My encode function for PySpark will properly encode a single row but I can't see to get it to be applied to the whole DataFrame. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

**Exception:**

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o463.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 2 in stage 15.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 2.0 in stage 15.0 (TID 38, localhost, executor driver): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.2.1/libexec/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 177, in main
    process()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.2.1/libexec/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 172, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.2.1/libexec/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 220, in dump_stream
    self.serializer.dump_stream(self._batched(iterator), stream)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.2.1/libexec/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 138, in dump_stream
    for obj in iterator:
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.2.1/libexec/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 209, in _batched
    for item in iterator:
  File "<string>", line 1, in <lambda>
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.2.1/libexec/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 71, in <lambda>
    return lambda *a: f(*a)
  File "<ipython-input-1-e5915375e985>", line 13, in encode
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/avro/schema.py", line 1284, in Parse
    return SchemaFromJSONData(json_data, names)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/avro/schema.py", line 1255, in SchemaFromJSONData
    return parser(json_data, names=names)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/avro/schema.py", line 1132, in _SchemaFromJSONString
    schema = names.GetSchema(name=json_string)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/avro/schema.py", line 417, in GetSchema
    avro_name = self.GetName(name=name, namespace=namespace)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/avro/schema.py", line 398, in GetName
    return Name(name=name, namespace=namespace)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/avro/schema.py", line 312, in __init__
    'Invalid absolute schema name: %r.' % self._fullname)
avro.schema.SchemaParseException: Invalid absolute schema name: '\n{\n    "namespace": "kakfa-avro.test",\n     "type": "record",\n     "name": "User",\n     "fields":[\n         {   "name": "name",  "type": "string"},\n         {   "name": "num", "type": ["int", "null"]}\n     ]\n}\n'.
```

Comment: Missing `lit` (like `encode_udf(lit(SCHEMA), ...)`)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass a constant value to Python UDF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35375255/how-to-pass-a-constant-value-to-python-udf)

Comment: hmmm I get `AttributeError: module 'avro' has no attribute 'schema'` when I add `lit(SCHEMA)`

Comment: It looks like some other mixup. What it you import in the function?

Comment: @user8371915 I'm not sure what you mean? All my imports are declared at the top of the code block.

Comment: On a side note I see you copied code from [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47952472/8371915) - I'd appreciate [attribution](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/attribution-required/).

Comment: `def encode(schema, row): import avro.schema ...`

Comment: @user8371915 I'll certainly add the attribution. Thanks for letting me know about it.

Comment: Also you could use Scala code directly -  [How to use a Scala class inside Pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36023860/8371915) as Python Avro used to be very slow.

Comment: That is cool didn't know about that. Looks like importing `avro.schema` in the encode function doesn't solve the exception...

Comment: At first glance the code looks valid, but I have no Python 2 installation to test it. Could you post a full traceback?

Comment: I'm using python3... there is an `avro-python3` package. Anyway, I closed the PySpark shell then move the avro imports to the encode function and that seemed to solve the import exception. Now I'm getting a `avro.schema.SchemaParseException: Invalid absolute schema name` exception. Posting above...

Comment: I see two problems a) There should be no `json.dumps` - data is already JSON `str`. b) Schema name cannot contain hypen if I remember correctly.

Comment: @moku were you able to resolve this issue?