# Spark batch write to Kafka topic from multi-column DataFrame

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, apache-spark-sql

After the batch, Spark ETL I need to write to Kafka topic the resulting DataFrame that contains multiple different columns.

According to the following Spark documentation https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html the Dataframe being written to Kafka should have the following mandatory column in schema:

> value (required)  string or binary

As I mentioned previously, I have much more columns with values so I have a question - how to properly send the whole DataFrame row as a single message to Kafka topic from my Spark application? Do I need to join all of the values from all columns into the new DataFrame with a single value column(that will contain the joined value) or there is more proper way to achieve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proper way to do that is already hinted by the docs, and doesn't really differ form what you'd do with any Kafka client - you have to serialize the payload before sending to Kafka.

How you you'll do that ([`to_json`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@to_json(e:org.apache.spark.sql.Column):org.apache.spark.sql.Column), [`to_csv`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/466d011d3515723653e41d8b1d0b6150b9945f52/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.scala#L3840), [Apache Avro](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47951668)) depends on your business requirements - nobody can answers this but you (or your team).