# Writing dataframe to kafka topic in an avro format for spark < 2.4?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, avro, spark-avro

Q1. Considering I have a dataframe `df` and a schema `myschema`, how do I proceed to write the dataframe into kafka topic in an avro format ?

Q2. Is there any optimized way if we do not consider `udf` ?

Most of the available solutions are for spark > 2.4 where they have inbuilt avro functions to use.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spark Dataframe write to kafka topic in avro format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47951668/spark-dataframe-write-to-kafka-topic-in-avro-format)

Comment: I tried, from there,
`eventDF.select(
      encodeUDF(struct(eventDF.columns.map(column):_*)).alias("value")
    )`
 `struct` and `column` was showing red in color, could you please help me in defining these select  query

Comment: 1) Are you using the Schema Registry? 2) They are read because you never defined/imported  them

Comment: This docs page is correct, if you are **not** using Schema Registry 

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-avro.html#to_avro-and-from_avro

Answer (score 0):

> Most of the available solutions are for spark > 2.4 where they have inbuilt avro functions

That inbuilt function [was an external library](https://github.com/databricks/spark-avro/blob/branch-4.0/README-for-old-spark-versions.md), but was later merged in to the main Spark project. If you have < 2.4, I suggest you upgrade you ultimately upgrade your Spark cluster, or refer the docs there.